# HyperLinkButton and Button doesn't work in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I make an app in VS2013 for Windows 8 and I try add HyperLinkButton and Button to project. When I test app Button and HyperLinkButton doesn't work.

```
        <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="http://web2edu.ru/shared/default.aspx"
                     Content="Log"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="1174,0,7,0"/>
```

It's a code from MainPage.xaml

Comment: pls post the code you tried.

Comment: Code was added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1174,0,7,0" >
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://web2edu.ru/shared/default.aspx" >
       Log
    </Hyperlink>
 </TextBlock>
```

Ref link : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8f22d5fe-b8eb-4949-9484-f60e9dd1eed6/hyperlinkbutton-does-not-exist?forum=wpf